# nil requires a contextual type

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code

```
protocol Transmittable : Codable {
    
}

extension Transmittable {
    func encode() -> Data {
        var data:Data = Data()
        try? data = JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        return data
    }
    
    static func decode(from data:Data?) -> Self? {
        guard let data = data else {
            return nil
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let response = try? decoder.decode(self, from: data)
        return response
    }
}

final class APICaller {
    
    private let baseUrl:String = "http://localhost:8080/"

    static let sharedInstance = APICaller()
    
    private init() {}
    
    func performCallToEndpoint<T : Transmittable>(_ endpoint:String, using method:String, body:Transmittable?, responseType: T.Type, completion: @escaping (_ error:Error?, _ serverError: T?, _ response:T?) -> Void) {
        
        let request = createURLRequest(toEndpoint: endpoint, using:method, body: body)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                completion(error, nil, nil)
                return
            }
            
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                guard httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                    let serverResponse = T.decode(from: data)
                    completion(nil, serverResponse, nil)
                    return
                }
            }
            
            let serverResponse = T.decode(from: data)
            completion(nil, nil, serverResponse)
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func createURLRequest(toEndpoint endpoint:String, using method:String, body:Transmittable?) -> URLRequest {
        let url = URL(string: baseUrl + endpoint)!
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = method
        if let body = body {
             request.httpBody = body.encode()
        }
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        return request
    }
}
```

when I call `APICaller.sharedInstance.performCallToEndpoint("/books", using: "GET", body: nil, responseType: nil) { (error, serverError, response) -> () in`

I get the error "nil requires a contextual type" where it says

```
body: nil
```

What should I do?

Comment: responseType: T.Type  is not nil, did you try making it an optional type?

Comment: You could make a empty struct conform to Transmittable and use it instead of nil

`struct EmptyTransmittable: Transmittable {}

APICaller.sharedInstance.performCallToEndpoint("", using: "", body: nil, responseType: EmptyTransmittable.self) { _, _, _ in}`

Comment: Now I get the error "For-in loop requires 'EmptyTransmittable' to conform to 'Sequence'"

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned the way you call your function doesn't make sense and it's hard to get your code to work 100% but here is some suggestions for fixes that should help you move forward.

First I added an enum for the different HTTP methods since it makes things type safer and IMO somewhat easier to read.

```
enum HTTPMethod: String {
    case GET
    case POST
    // ... other methods you support
}
```

Then we make two changes to the function declaration, make the `responsType` optional and use the new enum

```
func performCallToEndpoint<T : Transmittable>(_ endpoint:String,
                                              using method: HTTPMethod,
                                              body: Transmittable?,
                                              responseType: T.Type?,
                                              completion: @escaping (_ error:Error?, _ serverError: T?, _ response:T?) -> Void) {
```

Then inside the function you need to change the usage of `responseType`

```
if let data, let responseType { 
    let serverResponse = responseType.decode(from: data)
    completion(nil, nil, serverResponse)
} else {
    let error = ...
    completion(error, nil, nil)
}
```

I am not sure how the part below is supposed to work but I guess you need an extra parameter for holding the response type for a server error

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
    guard httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
        let serverResponse = T.decode(from: data) // You can't use T here 
        completion(nil, serverResponse, nil)
        return
    }
}
```

An example

```
struct SomeType: Transmittable {
    //...
}

APICaller.sharedInstance.performCallToEndpoint("/books", 
                                               using: APICaller.HTTPMethod.GET, 
                                               body: nil,
                                               responseType: SomeType.self) { (error, serverError, response) -> () in

}
```

Comment: @ChrisHansen any feedback on this?